# Is there a way to programmatically add a component to the tree when working with custom components?

Tags: jsf, composite-component, myfaces

We have a custom component library that basically just decorates the stock Faces components with Bootstrap classes (basically a successor to the now-dead BootFaces project).

What we're trying to do is have a theme of "the whole kitchen sink" with forms... so when you add an input component, it automatically includes a bit of padding around the object, a label, the actual input, then a message for the input.

One way to solve this would be to implement a bunch of composite components: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info but there are some cases where we need pretty tight control of whats being rendered, as bootstrap has some funny quirks.

So in the case of the input component, we want the developer to do something like:

```
<mf:inputText .../>
```

but really that gives them:

```
- inputTextParent
   - padding component
     - label component
     - actual input field component
     - message component
```

In the inputTextParent, is there a proper way to modify the component tree and add sub-components? **More importantly** If someone does this:

```
<mf:inputText ...>
  <h:somethingElse ../>
</mf:inputText>
```

Is there a way to delegate `<h:somethingElse ../>` to a child component?

```
- inputTextParent
   - padding component
     - label component
     - actual input field component
       - h:somethingElse
     - message component
```

Right now, we're doing roughly doing this in the contructor of the component... which will not properly delegate `h:somethingElse` to be a subchild of `actual input field component`. And I'm sure this is not a legal time to manipulate the component tree!

```
public MFInputTextComponentParent() {
    setRendererType(getComponentName());
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final Application application = context.getApplication();
    final MFPadComponent pad = (MFPadComponent) application.createComponent(MFPadComponent.COMPONENT);
    pad.setPadType("y");
    pad.setPad(1);
    super.getChildren().add(pad);
    final MFInternalLabelComponent label = (MFInternalLabelComponent) application
            .createComponent(MFInternalLabelComponent.COMPONENT);
    pad.getChildren().add(label);
    final MFInternalInputTextComponentParent inputText = createInternalInputText(application);
    pad.getChildren().add(inputText);
    final MFInternalMessageComponent message = (MFInternalMessageComponent) application
            .createComponent(MFInternalMessageComponent.COMPONENT);
    pad.getChildren().add(message);
}
```

Comment: Composite components will end up as a facet named `javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME` in the component tree.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered by Java SE experts

Comment: Jasper, I appreciate your opinion, but if you don't mind, please leave as is. I'm using Java to programmatically modify a component framework. Thank you.

Comment: "Java: This tag is frequently used alongside other tags for libraries and/or frameworks used by Java developers."

Comment: "Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to use `PostAddToViewEvent` to further populate the JSF view root tree with additional child components. Crucial here is to give each component you add a unique ID. See also section 2.12 Dynamic Components of:
https://github.com/e-Contract/enterprise-jsf/releases/download/enterprise-jsf-1.3.0/enterprise-jsf.pdf

Comment: Frank thank you for the reply. I have two followup questions. Is that id have to be globally unique or unique within the name container? Also, if the ID is left blank, would it be autogenerated? Thank you again.

Comment: IDs should be unique within the naming container as usual. Normally the facelets tag handling takes care of implicit autogenerated IDs. But in case you manually create a component, you need to put explicit IDs.